# how to count no of red pixels in an image using python open cv?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm Currently working on a project in which I need to count the no of red,blue,green,yellow,orange and violet pixels present in an image. As I am new to opencv I can't find any method that could solve my issues...

Comment: Please show us some code, some effort you have been going through.

Comment: You have to define what is red? pure red as in RGB [255, 0, 0] or any shade of red? if it is the latter you should use HSV, it makes easier to get the correct color and then count them :)

Comment: I see that you want to count a number of red, blue and violet pixels. But violet is a mixture of red and blue. Have I understood correctly that you want just to calculate a number of pixels that have some hard defined RGB color value?

Comment: I see that you want to count a number of red, blue and violet pixels. But violet is a mixture of red and blue. Have I understood correctly that you want just to calculate a number of pixels that have some hard defined RGB color value?

Answer (score 4):

A good start would be the [tutorial here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html), using histograms to plot the colors of an image. It looks like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('home.jpg')
color = ('b','g','r')
for i,col in enumerate(color):
     histr = cv2.calcHist([img],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
     plt.plot(histr,color = col)
     plt.xlim([0,256])
plt.show()
```

After a better understanding of OpenCV, you can easily adapt to solve your initial problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same easily without using open cv.

Suppose you have a image  named **analysis.PNG**, so in order to find the RGB percentage you can use the following code..

```
    from scipy import misc
    def picture_to_arr(image):
        arr = misc.imread(image)
        arr_list=arr.tolist()
        r=g=b=0
        for row in arr_list:
            for item in row:
                r=r+item[0]
                g=g+item[1]
                b=b+item[2]  
        total=r+g+b
        red=r/total*100
        green=g/total*100
        blue=b/total*100
        print ("the percentage of red content=",red,"%")
        print ("the percentage of green content=",green,"%")
        print ("the percentage of blue content=",blue,"%")


    picture_to_arr('analysis.PNG')
```